# Copy div and underlying content to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For facial recognition I use trackingjs to draw a div over an image on the place of the location of the face.

I would like to store the content (base64) of the div and its underlying html elements (in particular the image) using javascript / jquery.

```
<div class="demo-frame">
    <div class="demo-container">
        <img id="picture" src="http://domain/assets/example/img/example_photo.jpg">
        <div id="crop-image" class="rect" style="width: 107px; height: 107px; left: 704px; top: 135px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could this be done through jquery / javascript ?

Comment: You can draw the image on a canvas and draw a rectangle with the same size and position as the `div` on top of the image then use `toDataURL()` to get  a `base64` representation of that canvas.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to copy the content into another part of the page, you can use [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function in JQuery.

```js
  $(function(){
    var $copy = $('.demo-frame').clone();
    $('#copyto').html($copy);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo-frame">
    <div class="demo-container">
        <img id="picture" src="http://domain/assets/example/img/example_photo.jpg">
        <div id="crop-image" class="rect" style="width: 107px; height: 107px; left: 704px; top: 135px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="copyto"></div>
```